PQC Implementation of ML-KEM and ML-DSA
I am trying  to implement the NIST Post-Quantum Cryptography algorithms ML-KEM and ML-DSA (derived from CRYSTALS-Kyber and -Dilithium as specified in NIST FIPS-203 and NIST FIPS-204 respectively using a combination of hard- and software.
For both algorithms, considering the performance and the hardware cost, which function is suitable for hardware implementation?
Specifically which of the NTT/INVNTT, the Polynomial calculation or the Matrix calculation be implemented in hardware?

Note that I've spoken to smart card vendors that implemented the schemes in software (!). If you're going to implement this in hardware then you'll need to specify what kind of hardware you're requiring - or the use case at the very minimum. Note that, in principle anything can be implemented in hardware.

Please use the correct naming for algorithms. FIPS-203 and -204 are standards that contain algorithms which are defined by name. Quite often standards contain multiple algorithms, e.g. you'd expect an algorithm for key pair generation in a standard for asymmetric cryptography. Otherwise we get idiotic names in API's such as Rfc2898DeriveBytes while that standard defines both PBKDF1 and PBKDF2.

It of course gets a bit tricky if you get standards from NIST that forgets to define the standard by name such as the one for KBKDF's but I digress...

Whatever that's implemented in hardware cannot be changed, so you need to ensure that it's usable by as wide range of parameters as possible.
The CRYSTALS team give consideration for this by instantiating the schemed using module lattice with 256-degree polynomial as the underlying ring, so yes, NTT and InvNTT should be implemented in hardware. Also as part of matrix multiplication, polynomial addition and (NTT domain) multiplication should be implemented in hardware.
Matrix multiplication should be done in software, since the size of the matrix changes based on the parameter and the security level. It should invoke the underlying polynomial addition and multiplication. Hashing should also be done in software, although the 1600-bit Keccak permutation can be reused and should go in hardware.

Thanks for your answer. If I just implemt NTT/InvNTT, polynomial addition and multiplication by HW, when SW executes the matrix multiplication, SW needs to configure the polynomial coefficients and trigger HW many times. Is it very bad for performance?  If the Matrix size of the HW Matrix multiplication block can be configured by SW, is the performance much better than HW polynomial calculation only?

"trigger HW many times. Is it very bad for performance?" Actually, this part that you've described is the necessary computation - it's not avoidable, and has very little overhead (other than data copying, which can be made very fast by use of GDDR or faster chips and/or communication channel).
